# How can I make users choose their Google Chrome profile when they launch Chrome?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, user-accounts

I have a number of employees who use the same desktop.  Almost everything we do is in the browser.

I would like them to see Chrome's Manage People page, and then click their profile.

Example of the inerface I'm referring to:

[image]

Can I do this?  If so, how?

My ideas were:  if there's a chrome://manage-users or some direct url like that I could make that the home page.  I'm a web designer, so I if there's a way to write a URL so that it opens a different user's profile, I could make my own user chooser page instead.

Most of the computers they're using are running google-chrome on Linux Mint, but there are a few Windows 10 machines.

I'd like to avoid setting up individual Operating System logins, since I'd need to do that on every single PC, and it can take quite a while to switch OS user.

**Edit:** I was able to get the direct link with some help from [@NotWaldorf](https://twitter.com/notwaldorf/status/871866830897295361)  on Twitter: [chrome://md-user-manager/](http://chrome://md-user-manager/)

Comment: You can make chrome shortcuts on your desktop for every user. Would that be enough?  http://prntscr.com/fbfnjr

Comment: @User552853 It would be an option, but It would mean managing those shortcuts on every desktop of every machine individually.  The Manage User page is dynamic, and lists all users.  Or, if I were to host a webpage, I would only have to update that in one place.